# Unexpected random shutdowns in Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, shutdown

Recently my Samsung Galaxy S2 has been doing this very strange thing, it just switches off on its own. However the screen flickers like two or three times really quickly before it switches off.

It all started when i went on holiday and the signal was poor up in the mountain (not sure if this helps but i'm gonna type it anyway). so since then I've had it on flight mode accessing WiFi only and making use of Bluetooth, yet it still randomly does it. are there any logs I can check to maybe see what the problem is!?

Comment: With the information you supplied it could be a lot of things. A full log report will help a lot. [How do I get the log file from an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic shut off can mean any of these;

- too many running applications running in the background. (Start your your phone in CLOCKWORLD and select to clear CACHE)
- refrain from charging your phone while playing games and running so many applications as this may speed up the aging of your battery.
- maybe its time you replace your battery if the above doesnt seem to work.

Comment: i'm so smart lol. OK today i actually did do the following:
1. Started in Recovery mode
2. Clearded the dalvik cache
3. Fixed permissions

this seems to have done the trick, just gonna use it for a day then see. thanks for your help

Comment: @CraigWayne if this fixed your problem you should accept it as the answer, you should also go back and accept answers to your other questions.

Comment: thanks for all the help but i think the problem is my battery, i'm pretty sure, cyanogenmod has never failed me before AND also the battery has a bump on it as a result of misuse and abuse whilst on charge. thanks everyone though.

Comment: Just to clarify: the second bullet was the cause of the problem.